# Cannot catch SIGINT signal in a producer-consumer program where JNI is used in consumer thread

Tags: java, c++, multithreading, boost, jvm

I am writing a program for a producer-consumer problem.

Producer produces data and pushes data into `boost::spsc_queue` and the consumer processes it.

In consumer thread, I am using `JNI` to call some java functions from my code written in c++.

I am `initializing and creating JVM` in the function itself called by the consumer thread and then the event loop starts in which it pops data from `boost::spsc_queue` and process it.

Now, I want to catch `SIGINT` signal, so I have written a `signal_handler` and register it in my `main()` function. But it is not working.

If I comment out all JNI stuff and just start a loop `while(1){}` there in the function called by consumer thread, then it is catching SIGINT and working as it is supposed to work.

Is something more which I need to take care for JVM or JNI stuff?
Shall I try the same thing after initializing and creating JVM in the main thread? Does it make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems, you need the [`-Xrs` option](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/java.html#BABHDABI)

> #### -Xrs
>
> Reduces the use of operating system signals by the JVM.
>
> …
>
> Applications embedding the JVM frequently need to trap signals such as `SIGINT` or `SIGTERM`, which can lead to interference with the JVM signal handlers. The `-Xrs` option is available to address this issue. When `-Xrs` is used, the signal masks for `SIGINT`, `SIGTERM`, `SIGHUP`, and `SIGQUIT` are not changed by the JVM, and signal handlers for these signals are not installed.
>
> There are two consequences of specifying `-Xrs`:
>
> - `SIGQUIT` thread dumps are not available.
> - User code is responsible for causing shutdown hooks to run, for example, by calling `System.exit()` when the JVM is to be terminated.

You can specify such options in the `JavaVMInitArgs` which you pass to [`JNI_CreateJavaVM(…)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html#overview).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, JVM uses signal handlers for its own purpose, that's why you need to care about signal chaining specially. [Read more >](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/signals-139944.html#gbzcz)