# Not receiving the Native SIGIO signals in serial port calling from Java thread

Tags: java, c, serial-port, java-native-interface, signals

I need to create a JNI c library for patient monitor subsystem under Linux platform. I have to read the data and write the command through USB Serial port. Whenever the port is open, the device sends multiple types of data continuously with different frequencies and sizes.

From Java, I am running a separate thread which calls the native jni c code, there I am calling a C-function to read data from serial port in while(1) loop based on RX_Flag which was enabled inside the signal handler. The signal handler function is connected with SIGIO using sigaction during port configuration. My expectation is, whenever the data arrives in the port, triggers the signal, that signal is connected to the signalIO handler, enables the RX_Flag.

Based on flag_values, reads, parses and sends back the array to Java. I am calling the receive function using pthread from main in C, it was working fine. But from Java, I was stuck in the first step itself. Am not receiving the IO Signals properly, after sometime IO Signals not arrived. In Native C, whenever the IO signal arrives, it enables the flag in a separate processes. For that, is there any additional things I have to add inside the Signal IOhandler?

Am I going in a correct way or is there an alternate way to implement this?

Comment: Provide your code, so that we may have a look.

Comment: Your two questions on Stack Overflow indicate that your expectations need to be changed a bit. Your readers are generally volunteers here, and they are here in their free time. It is therefore not ideal to set out any demands for answers, nor the time-frame in which you need answers.

Answer (score 1):

JVM uses signals for its own purposes, this is summarized in this thread [Cannot catch SIGINT signal in a producer-consumer program where JNI is used in consumer thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33419052/cannot-catch-sigint-signal-in-a-producer-consumer-program-where-jni-is-used-in-c). There was introduced a technique called *signal chaining* by java to handle this ...

> The signal-chaining facility was introduced to remedy a problem with
>   signal handling in previous versions of the Java HotSpot VM. Prior to
>   version 1.4, the Java HotSpot VM would not allow application-installed
>   signal handlers for certain signals including, for example, **SIGBUS,
>   SIGSEGV, SIGILL, etc**, since those signal handlers could conflict with
>   the signal handlers used internally by the Java HotSpot VM

source :  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/signal-chaining.html

> If an application with native code requires its own signal handlers, then it might need to be used with the signal chaining facility

source : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/signals003.html

`SIGIO` is used by current JVM : https://github.com/JetBrains/jdk8u_hotspot/blob/master/src/os/linux/vm/jvm_linux.cpp

to verify that *SIGIO* is triggered you can use `strace` or `auditd` ( https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/aimsupport/entry/Finding_the_source_of_signals_on_Linux_with_strace_auditd_or_Systemtap?lang=en )